# FOTA : bypass post install setup process

Tags: android, installation, ota

I have an android "Firmware Over The Air" update.zip file created with **make otapackage**. The package installs correctly but after installation the user is required to "setup" the device by selecting various configuration options. Is there a flag in the install scripts to bypass the setup process or can I automate or bypass the post install setup process other than writing an app to automatically configure the device prior to the setup process kicking in after first boot?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I had to remove the SetupWizard.apk application from the /system/app/ folder.